# Why Does My Program Keep Crashing (C++)?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why this won't run properly in Visual Studio 2012

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

char nullChar()
{
    char ch;

    int ran = (rand() % 52);

    if (ran < 26) 
        {
            ch = (char) ('a'+ ran);
        } 
    else 
        {
            ch = (char) ('A'+ ran - 26);
        }

    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    cout << "Enter a string";

    int nullNum = 0;
    nullNum = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
        {
            int count = -1;

            do
                {
                    int c = cin.get();
                    count++;

                    if(count == nullNum)
                        {
                            cout.put(c);
                            count = -1;
                        }

                } while (!cin.eof()) ;
        }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0)
        {
            char c = cin.get();

            while(!cin.eof())
                {
                    for (int i = -1; i < (nullNum-1); ++i)
                        {
                            cout << nullChar();
                        }

                    cout << c;
                    c = cin.get();
                }
        }


}
```

The code compiles perfectly. I'm suspecting something in a loop but I can't figure it out. I also think it ran perfectly a few days ago but now it's not. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? And how do you run the program... for example you supply at least two command line parameters, right?

Comment: "Won't run properly" is a completely useless description of the problem. Is the output wrong? Does it get stuck in an infinite loop? Does it crash, and if so, with what message? Give us something to work with here. I wouldn't show you a picture of a car and say "why won't it start?".

Comment: what's the error? What are arguments you are calling your program with?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you passed a parameter. But aside from that you should always check argc before using argv[xyz]. My guess is you get a segfault, because there is no argv[1] and argv[2]